# Gradient Background in Frame XAML Element

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms mobile application that has a new UI implementation that requires a number of specific XAML elements to have gradient colors.

I have not been able to implement something or find a specific solution to apply linear-gradient background or similar for elements such as Frame.

I have tried to make use of SkiaSharp, MagicGradient and a number of other implementations but none can apply gradient colors to specific control elements such as Frame in Xamarin.Forms.

```
public Login()
{
 InitializeComponent();

 SKCanvasView canvasView = new SKCanvasView();
 canvasView.PaintSurface += OnCanvasViewPaintSurface;
 Content = canvasView;
}

private void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
 SKImageInfo info = e.Info;
 SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
 SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

 canvas.Clear();

 using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint())
 {
  // Create 300-pixel square centered rectangle
  float x = (info.Width - 300) / 2;
  float y = (info.Height - 300) / 2;
  SKRect rect = new SKRect(x, y, x + 300, y + 300);

  // Create linear gradient from upper-left to lower-right
  paint.Shader = SKShader.CreateLinearGradient(
  new SKPoint(rect.Left, rect.Top),
  new SKPoint(rect.Right, rect.Bottom),
  new SKColor[] { SKColors.Red, SKColors.Blue },
  new float[] { 0, 1 },
  SKShaderTileMode.Repeat);

  // Draw the gradient on the rectangle
  canvas.DrawRect(rect, paint);
}
}
```

Is there a way to get a linear effect on individual controls like Frame?

Updated with image to see the correct effect required.

[image: Image showing the effect required for the UI.]

Comment: Have you tried wrapping a `Grid` (or `AbsoluteLayout`)  in the Frame, add the `SKSurface` to that `Grid` and add the contents to the same `Grid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it by using **Custom Renderer**

#### in share Project

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace xxx
{
    public class GradientColorFrame:Frame
    {
        public Color StartColor { get; set; }
        public Color EndColor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### in iOS

```
using xxx;
using xxx.iOS;
using CoreAnimation;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GradientColorFrame), typeof(MyFrameRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {
        public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
        {
            base.Draw(rect);
            GradientColorFrame stack = (GradientColorFrame)this.Element;
            CGColor startColor = stack.StartColor.ToCGColor();

            CGColor endColor = stack.EndColor.ToCGColor();      

            var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();

            gradientLayer.Frame = rect;
            gradientLayer.Colors = new CGColor[] { startColor, endColor};

            NativeView.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradientLayer, 0);
            NativeView.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
            NativeView.Layer.CornerRadius = 100;
        }
    }
}
```

#### in Android

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Support.V4.Content.Res;
using xxx;
using xxx.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;


[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GradientColorFrame), typeof(MyFrameRenderer))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class MyFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {
        public MyFrameRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        private Xamarin.Forms.Color StartColor { get; set; }
        private Xamarin.Forms.Color EndColor { get; set; }


        public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.Draw(canvas);



            var gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, 0, Width, 0, this.StartColor.ToAndroid(), this.EndColor.ToAndroid(), Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Mirror);



            var paint = new Android.Graphics.Paint()
            {
                Dither = true,
                AntiAlias = true
            };
            paint.SetShader(gradient);
            var rect = new RectF(0, 0, canvas.Width, canvas.Height);

            canvas.DrawRoundRect(rect, 100f, 100f, paint); // set CornerRadius  here 
        }

       
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
        {
           

            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                var stack = e.NewElement as GradientColorFrame;
                this.StartColor = stack.StartColor;
                this.EndColor = stack.EndColor;
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR:", ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
 
}
```

#### in xaml

```
<local:GradientColorFrame StartColor="Blue" EndColor="Red" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300">
   //...            
</local:GradientColorFrame>
```

Comment: This works, however the CornerRadius is not working after implementing this. Is there a way of making sure all the properties for Frame work?

Comment: @EdwardWhitehead The reason `CornerRadius` is not working could be that you are setting the `Padding` to 0 and then not setting `IsClippedToBounds` true. Good luck!

Comment: @FreakyAli unfortunately, this did not work either.

CornerRadius="10" Margin="20, 180, 20, 0" IsClippedToBounds="True"  Padding="20"

Comment: If you have the padding remove the clipped to bounds and it should work

Comment: @FreakyAli thanks for your help, but this still does not work, no matter what I do. I have tried multiple ways of getting it to work with no luck.

Comment: Which platform did you test?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT - currently testing on Android.

Comment: I have also just discovered that anything nested within this custom renderer also has the gradient applied to the children. :-(

Comment: Did you test the solution from https://github.com/tbaggett/xfgloss?

Comment: Yes I did and it does not work as expected. It focuses on Cells rather than components such as frame.

Comment: Hi @LucasZhang-MSFT this worked perfectly. Do you perhaps know how children controls can be implemented within <local:GradientColorFrame ...//...</local:GradientColorFrame> and not have the gradient applied to them as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202208/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-edward-whitehead).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this NuGet for Gradient implementation.
https://github.com/tbaggett/xfgloss